# How can I order a List according to my own rules?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ query :

```
IEnumerable<MyScheda> schede = from MyScheda scheda in new MySchede()
                               select scheda;
```

and I'd like to order this list according to the field `scheda.Note`, which can contains Saturday, Monday, Sunday, and so on.

So, how you can wish, I'd like to order them as the usual order or the day.
How can I do it?

Comment: What type is the `Note` field?

Comment: See also my answer here: [How to enforce rule-based object ordering when inserting into a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886148/9910401#9910401) Using that you'd define Monday < Tuesday, Tuesday < Wednesday etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IEnumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) extension method with your own comparer:

```
IEnumerable<MyScheda> schede = (from MyScheda scheda in new MySchede()
                               select scheda).OrderBy(s => s.Note, new DaysOfWeekComparer());
```

of course you have to implement `DaysOfWeekComparer()` before.

Comment: See my answer here for a way of implementing `DaysOfWeekComparer`. [How to enforce rule-based object ordering when inserting into a list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9886148)

Answer (score 0):

You can request an ordering by using **orderby**:

```
List<String> names=new List<String>();

...

foreach(String name in from String s in names orderby s.Length select s)
{
...
}
```

In your case, I believe you'll want to use:

```
orderby scheda.Note
```

This assumes, of course, that the type of Note can be compared for ordering.  If it cannot be compared directly, you will need to write a some code that converts a "Note-type" to a sortable type, and then use that rather than Note directly, like this:

```
int NoteIndexer(NoteType n);

IEnumerable<MyScheda> schede = from MyScheda scheda in new MySchede() 
    orderby NoteIndexer(scheda.Note)
    select scheda;
```

Comment: If Note is a string/varchar field it would not be sorted in Days order

Comment: Granted, my response does depend on the type of Note being comparable in the order that he wants them.  However, there is no additional information as to the type of Note.  If more information comes out we can elucidate the solution a bit but do you feel that this response is a reasonable starting point?

Comment: It's an ok starting point, but it's probably work mentioning the requirement that the field is of the correct type in the answer. :)